# Status Bar icon color in CupertinoNavigationBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

for some time I'm facing a problem with the status bar icons color, when I'm using flutter AppBar i can change the status bar icon brightness without any problem but the issue starts when I'm trying to use the Cupertino style NavigationBar. The status bar icon are always dark, at the start of the app I'm using:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(statusBarColor: kTeal),
  );
```

to change the status bar color and its icon brightness and it works but immediately when I use CupertinoNavBar with teal background color the icons change to dark and I need them to stay white. Is there any solution to change their color or is it just a fixed logic inside and there is no way to change the brightness of those icons ?

Thanks in advance for any help.